# How to get the top values within each group?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am new to Pandas and I have a dataset that looks something like this.

```
s_name  Time        p_name  qty
A       12/01/2019  ABC     1
A       12/01/2019  ABC     1
A       12/01/2019  DEF     2
A       12/01/2019  DEF     2
A       12/01/2019  FGH     0
B       13/02/2019  ABC     3
B       13/02/2019  DEF     1
B       13/02/2019  DEF     1
B       13/03/2019  ABC     3
B       13/03/2019  FGH     0
```

I am trying to group by s_name and find the sum of the qty of each unique p_name in a month but only display the p_name with the top 2 most quantities. Below is an example of how I want the final output to look like.

```
s_name  Time        p_name  qty
A       01          DEF     4
A       01          ABC     2
B       02          ABC     3
B       02          DEF     2
B       03          ABC     2
B       03          FGH     0
```

Do you have any ideas? I have been stuck here for quite long so much help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the text instead of images.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa I have edited. Sorry as I don't post much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `month` using [`dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html), then group by `s_name` and `month`, then [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) a function to the groups, group each group by `name` and do a `sum` over  `qty`, [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) descending and only get the first two rows with [`head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['month'] = df.Time.dt.month

df_f = df.groupby(['s_name', 'month']).apply(
    lambda df:
        df.groupby('p_name').qty.sum()
        .sort_values(ascending=False).head(2)
).reset_index()

df_f
#   s_name  month   p_name  qty
# 0 A   1   DEF 4
# 1 A   1   ABC 2
# 2 B   2   ABC 3
# 3 B   2   DEF 2
# 4 B   3   ABC 3
# 5 B   3   FGH 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I am new to Pandas myself. I am going to attempt to answer your question.

See this code.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

columns = "s_name Time p_name qty"

# Create dataframe from text.
df = pd.read_csv(
    StringIO(
        f"""{columns}
A 12/01/2019 ABC 1
A 12/01/2019 ABC 1
A 12/01/2019 DEF 2
A 12/01/2019 DEF 2
A 12/01/2019 FGH 0
B 13/02/2019 ABC 3
B 13/02/2019 DEF 1
B 13/02/2019 DEF 1
B 13/03/2019 ABC 3
B 13/03/2019 FGH 0"""
    ),
    sep=" ",
)


S_NAME, TIME, P_NAME, QTY = columns.split()
MONTH = "month"

# Convert the TIME col to datetime types.
df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, dayfirst=True)


# Create a month column with zfilled strings.
df[MONTH] = df.Time.apply(lambda x: str(x.month).zfill(2))


# Group
group = df.groupby(by=[S_NAME, P_NAME, MONTH])


gdf = (
    group.sum()
    .sort_index()
    .sort_values(by=[S_NAME, MONTH, QTY], ascending=False)
    .reset_index()
)

gdf.groupby([S_NAME, MONTH]).head(2).sort_values(by=[S_NAME, MONTH]).reset_index()
```

Is this the result you expected?

[image]